# Adding rows to top of TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, row, tablelayoutpanel

I'm trying to add new rows to my tablelayoutpanel at the top of it. For that purpose I use the following code:

**Initialization**

```
TableLayoutPanel panel = new TableLayoutPanel();
panel.ColumnCount = 1;
panel.RowCount = 1;
panel.AutoScroll = true;
panel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(280, 52);
panel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(308, 189);
panel.Visible = true;
panel.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
Controls.Add(panel);
```

**For each new row**

```
panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));
panel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 16F));
panel.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = text, AutoSize = false, ForeColor = Color.White, Font = font }, 0, 0);
panel.RowCount = panel.RowCount + 1;
```

**ISSUE**
It seems to work fine until I add 4 rows. For example:

*ITERATION 1* -->
Player 1

*ITERATION 2* -->
Player 2
Player 1

*ITERATION 3* -->
Player 3
Player 2
Player 1

*ITERATION 4* -->
Player 4
Player 3
Player 2
Player 1

Here comes the issue

*ITERATION 5* -->
Player 4
Player 5
Player 3
Player 2
Player 1

Do you have any idea about what could be going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After adding the row, you need to push all of the controls down a row, then insert your new control:

```
panel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 16F));
panel.RowCount++;
foreach (Control c in panel.Controls) {
  panel.SetRow(c, panel.GetRow(c) + 1);
}
panel.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = text }, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know. Thanks.

Comment: How do you push the row up using the designer?

Comment: @Legends The table designer has options to add, delete or insert new rows.  There isn't a "move up" or "move down" option.